# Compare two strings containing "expressions" for equality

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two strings, the one is `"K <- L * 5"` and the other is `"K <- 5 * L"`

Is there a way to say in Python 3 to compare these and return `True` ? ( because they are the same but in different order )

I'm looking for a solution to compare only the 2nd part, after `<-`

Specifically I'd like the second part to give the same result.

E.g.

- `"5 % 3"` and `"3 % 5"` are not the same
- `"L * 5"` and `"5 * L"` are the same

Maybe a dictionary could help, but I'm not familiar with Python.

Comment: A huge problem is that it is an undecidable problem to check if two expressions are semantically the sae. Furthermore it is not specified what the "grammar" of the expressions is.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Are you sure this problem is undecidable? Which one is it on the list https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_undecidable_problems? I feel it is "just" NP-hard.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately you picked a question thats kinda offtopic , namely asking for a offsite lib/tut/... - Please go over [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and 
[on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) again and if you have questions provide 
your code as [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If you encounter errors, copy and paste
the error message verbatim ( word for word) into your question. Avoid using screenshots unless you 
need to convey layout errors.

Comment: @DYZ It's the same problem that makes it undecidable whether two regular expressions are equivalent.

Comment: @DYZ: It depends on how complex the language is of course. But the Equivalence problem of two Turing machines us undecidable (and even co-undecidable).

Comment: There are however modules to build parsers, ([pyparse](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/) f.e. never used it myself, just found by googeling) which would enable you to parse your expression into tokens that you could analyze.

Comment: @Tomalak: finding out if two regular expressions are equivalent is in fact decidable (it is even in P if I recall correctly)

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem The problem of stopping a Turing machine is undecidable. But here, we are not asking whether the machines stop, because they represent memory-less expressions and always stop in a finite number of steps.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Given a list of equivalences like A+B==B+A, one can generate every possible equivalent expression.

Comment: @DYZ: how do we know that? As said before, it depends on how expressive the language is. Also if the size of the integers (in Python it is) is arbitrary.

Comment: @DYZ: it is not because we can generate every equivalent expression, that we eventually will find out if the two are equivalent. Since the number of expressions can be infinite, so in that case by simply enumerating, we will never know if the two are *not* equivalent.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Regardless of the size of integers, A+B==B+A, isn't it?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem The number of permutations of a finite string is finite. Theoretically, you are right. Practically, not.

Comment: @DYZ: for addition, that of course holds, but here you oversimplify the problem. If you for instance take as an example rule `A == A+B-B`. Then we can thus generate out of `2 == 2+1-1 == 2+1-1+1-1 == ...`, but we will never stop generating new expressions, so we can not *by simply enumerating* proof that `2` is not equal to `2 + 1 - 0`.

Comment: @DYZ: but as said before, you make the assumption that it is only a matter of permutations. Take for instance `K <- L` and `K <- L /3 * 3`. If we take rounding into account, than `L / 3 * 3` is not always equal to `L`. So even in a practical sense it is terribly hard. From the moment there is some mechanism of arbitrary deeply nested loops, then we can simply use Rice's theorem to proof that it is undecidable.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Ok, I guess you are right. However, the OP could add more restrictions to make the problem decidable. E.g., define equivalence strictly in terms of permutations.

Comment: We can of design a system that can conservatively proof that the two are equivalent (in some cases), so that `A + B` is `B + A`. But we can not do this in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the comments, the check of semantics in this is an obstacle. You could probably build your own (or find someone else's) grammatical parser for these kind of mathematical expressions.

A workaround would be to use the mathematical capability that is already built in and converting the expression to valid expressions. I chose here to convert all numbers and letters to their Ascii equivalent. You can choose yourself how picky you want to be in the conversion (lower all caps, use only certain alphabets etc...) but here is a working example.

```
def main():

opt1_raw = "K <- N * 5" 
opt2_raw = "K <- 5 * N"

opt1 = opt1_raw.split("<-")[1]
opt2 = opt2_raw.split("<-")[1]

ascii_exp = ''.join([str(ord(char)) if char.isdigit() or char.isalpha() else char for char in opt1])
s = eval(ascii_exp)

ascii_exp = ''.join([str(ord(char)) if char.isdigit() or char.isalpha() else char for char in opt2])
p = eval(ascii_exp)

print(opt1 +" and " + opt2 +": " + str(s==p))

main()
```

In the loop, I am converting all `digits` and `alphas` (letters) to their ascii equivalent, letting operators such as '`*`' and '`/`' be where they are. Then I use `eval()` to let python evaluate the expression. The result of an evaluation can then look like this: `76*53` instead of `"L*5"` Then I just compare the result. I'm sure you can find a more elegant way to incorporate this but its an example of evaluating such abstract expressions.

The output:

```
L*5 and 5*L: True
L*5 and 5 % 3: False
5 % 3 and 3 % 5: False
L*5 and 5 % 3: False
```

Comment: Worked, thank you. One issue is that if I give "M <- N * 5" and "N <- M * 5" the result is True, which ti isn't :) Any hint ?

Comment: Because eval() dont know how to correctly interpret "<-". I updated the answer with a parser that only takes the right-hand into account. You can probably work from here to customize it to do what you want it to do

Comment: Please accept this answer as a solution if it helped you.

Comment: I put also these lines to avoid to have wrong the first part : if (opt1[0] != opt2[0]) : sys.exit( ). Thanks again, the fact is I clicked the up arrow to accept it as a a solution but ignores me ( I'll try again ). I'm a new member, that's why..